# django, smtp write that password or name incorrect, but name and password correct

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

i have djnago app

when i try to start it
smtp write error in console, that name and password are incorrect, but name and password is correct!

this is my views.py
last function "SendEmailView" use function from utils.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Contact
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .utils import SendEmail


####################################################

class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

###################################################



def RegistrationView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password1)
        myuser.save()

        return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/registration.html")

###############################################

def SigninView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "emnosys/main.html")
        else:
            return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/signin.html")

################################################

def SignoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

######################################################

class PersonalPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/personalpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

####################################################

@login_required
def ContactCreateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('about--username')
        message = request.POST.get('about--textarea')
        email = request.POST.get('about--email')
        if not all([username, message, email]):
            return render(request, 'emnosys/addcontacts.html')
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            return render(request, 'emnosys/addcontacts.html')
        contact = Contact(username=username, message=message, email=email, contactowner=request.user)
        contact.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('personalpage'))
    return render(request, 'emnosys/addcontacts.html')


##################################


def SendEmailView(request):
    SendEmail()
    return redirect('/')
```

this is my utils.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from emnosys.models import Contact
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail, EmailMessage

message1 = EmailMessage(
    "Subject here",
    "Here is the message",
    "emnosys.wqrfl@gmail.com",
    ["pawwne27@gmail.com"],
)

message_tuple = ((message1.subject, message1.body, message1.from_email, message1.to),)

send_mass_mail(message_tuple, fail_silently=False)
```

this is my settings

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-++z-#m#q&_)yx%0j5uyros^t55glb480!!ys7g$2@qmi-8u@x#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'emnosys'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'emnosys_wqrfl.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'emnosys_wqrfl.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'emnosysdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '123123',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "emnosy.wqrfl@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "*here is correct password*"
```

when i try to start my django application i see that error

```
(venv) PS D:\projects\EmNoSy> cd venv
(venv) PS D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv> cd emnosys_wqrfl
(venv) PS D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, 
in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check      
    databases=databases,
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks  
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver  
    return check_method()
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 602, in url_patterns     
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module   
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl\emnosys_wqrfl\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', include('emnosys.urls')),
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl\emnosys\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl\emnosys\views.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .utils import SendEmail
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl\emnosys\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    send_mass_mail(message_tuple, fail_silently=False)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 87, in send_mass_mail
    return connection.send_messages(messages)
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 102, in send_mes
sages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 69, in open     
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\
smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  ht
tps://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g11-20020a2eb5cb000000b002c9ffbedc24sm91425ljn.122 - gsmtp'
)
```

i checked email and password, and it's really correct, i dont know what to do with it

Comment: EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "App Password" -- must be app password check how can you create app password for Gmail account  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5V6yicW-ao

Answer (score 0):

Error was in password, i tried to use email password, but it needed app password from gmail!